# Visual Studio 2008: automatic unloading of disabled project

Tags: visual-studio-2008

My Visual Studio solution file has lots of build configurations that significantly differ in which projects are enabled, and which are not. I'd like to automatically unload all projects that are turned off in active build configuration to save RAM and make VS faster. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Not without writing something yourself.

The data which indicates which projects are unloaded is kept in the `.suo` file that goes with the solution file, so one cheap hack way you could do it (before you write that cool VS extension) is to keep a different solution file for each major build configuration.

Comment: Yeah, i think it has merit. I can't possibly guess whether there would be enough demand that you could make some money from it, but i do think it would be one of those add-ins that once people start using it they will wonder how they managed to do without it. And it would save having multiple solution files to achieve the same thing.